# How do I form an SQL query with AND and ORs?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I want to write a query that returns all non-empty cells in column X AND whose values are not 2, 5, OR 8.  Am I doing this right?  Because my results sure look wrong.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Example].[dbo].[table]
WHERE X <> '' AND (X <> '2' OR X <> '5' OR X <> '8');
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not catching empty cells the right way?

Comment: do the columns allow null?

Comment: `X <> '2' OR X <> '5' OR X <> '8'` means that if it's different from ANY of them, it's true. Since it's hard not to be (if X=2, it is still different from 5 and 8 for example), the parenthesized expression is always true (unless NULL is invoved, and that does not seem to be the intention)

Comment: @Joachim thanks for helping me to better understand the logic.  i clearly had this wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by empty, you mean `NULL` (*nothing*) and `empty string` **is not equal** to `null` so you should use special condition to filter out non-`NULL` values using `IS NOT NULL`

```
WHERE X IS NOT NULL AND 
      X NOT IN('', '2', '5', '8');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Example].[dbo].[table]
WHERE X <> '' AND  X IS NOT NULL AND X NOT IN ('2','5','8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would write this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Example].[dbo].[table]
WHERE ISNULL(X,'') <> ''
AND X not in ('2','5','8');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not accounting for NULLS in this query.

```
X IS NOT NULL
```

I would take out your 'OR's' and just do and as you want ALL those criteria not one or the other.

Comment: crap, you're right.  i didn't realize that changing all those ors into ands achieves the result i want (aside from the null/empty thing).  thanks for pointing this out, +1.

Comment: In SQL you must always be aware of the NULLS.  They can kill your statements at times when you ignore them so best to try to remember them whenever possible.  Like a lot of people have shown to, I would use the 'In' or 'Not in' when listing a bunch of things you want to qualify out.  It is cleaner to look at IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Seems all other answers concentrate on filtering out `NULL` explicitly, however I thought I'd point out that `NULL` is a special case and `NULL NOT IN` anything is never true. That will simplify your query to just;

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE X NOT IN ('', '2','5','8')
```

This will select all rows where X is not `NULL`, '2', '5', '8' or the empty string.

If you want `NULL` *included*, you instead have to do the somewhat peculiar construct;

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE X IS NULL OR X NOT IN ('', '2', '5', '8');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8995c/1).